# How can I correctly to use HCI device with Bluez in linux

Tags: linux, bluez, hci

We are working to use external Bluetooth device though BlueZ 5.49 and HCI-UART.
After using btattach or hciattach , we use the hciconfig to check the device status but the device always show DOWN.

The log as bellowing:

```
# hciattach -b /dev/ttyS1 any 1000000
Device setup complete
#
# hciconfig hci0 up
Can't init device hci0: Cannot assign requested address (99)
#
#hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
        BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 27:7  SCO MTU: 0:0
        DOWN
        RX bytes:231 acl:0 sco:0 events:16 errors:0
        TX bytes:88 acl:0 sco:0 commands:16 errors:0
```

We use btmon to check hci command and the command was workable but the last HCI command was Set_Event_Mask_Page2. I checked several times and the result was always the same.

Does some one have such kind of experience ? or can suggest me which part I can look into??

Linux Kenerl :4.9.89-1.6,
BlueZ: 5.49

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Show `dmesg` as well. Is this custom chip? Did you have success with other Bluetooth devices like usb dongle or something?

Comment: Thanks .  I thought I finish the issue. I do the development to work with Ubuntu firstly and move to Linux environment. The different was the MGMT utility behavior was different. After adding btmgmt  and work, the hci function work well.